# Installing numpy in PyCharm on windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I'm using Python 3.8 and I'm trying to install numpy on PyCharm 2019.2 but I keep having this error.
I have been told that there are problems in pythons 3.8 and that is why I can't install numpy.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj _configtest.obj.d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\setup.py", line 444, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\setup.py", line 436, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
    r = self.setuptools_run()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
    return distutils_install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 142, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 286, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Comment: We’re going to need far more information than this.

Comment: It’s not clear what command caused the error, what actions led to this?

Comment: just put your code here...

Comment: The code is too long, I could n't post it.

Comment: I just tried to install it using; `pip3 install numpy` and I also tried using pip

Comment: Do you have to use 3.8?  Can you go back to 3.7 temporarily until this is fixed?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, but I couldn't download 3.7.4? I can't find it

Comment: @EnasAK What are you using to manage your packages and python versions? (I.e I use Conda, I recommend it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project and virtual environment in PyCharm. Then try downgrading your python to 3.7.2 and uninstall then reinstall numpy through the project settings in pycharm. In your python or bash terminal run,

```
conda install python == 3.7.2
```

If you don't have Anaconda Distribution downloaded then navigate to the "Project Interpreter" in PyCharm and you can install/uninstall libraries directly from there with the plus and minus icon. I think you may have a underlying system problem so going for a fresh install of the dependencies you are having issues with should remedy the problem along with stepping away from version 3.8 of Python.

Comment: You can also use that same GUI to manage packages when you’re using Conda. It even allows you to switch between packages installed with Conda and those installed with Pip.